# Cannot see some PDF annotations in Adobe Reader (or Mac Preview)

Tags: pdf, annotations, adobe, reader

I have received annotations on a PDF document from a colleague. He says he inserted them using Adobe Reader. The annotations consist of:
(a) notes in yellow boxes
(b) strikeout in red
(c) strikeout in blue plus a blue caret (triangle) with the suggested alternate text.

My problem is I cannot see the blue carets or suggested alternate text, either in Adobe Reader or Mac Preview. When I print with annotations from Mac Preview, the blue carets show up, but not the alternate text.

I am using an up-to-date version (Acrobat Adobe Reader DC Version 2019.012.20040, Mac OS), so I assume my problem is in my preferences. So... how do I ensure the blue carets (and all other feedback/notes) are displayed, in Adobe Reader? (or in Mac Preview, if that is easier)

Comment: To have us not guess wildly around, can you share an example of those weird files?

Comment: I can't put this particular document online. I'll see if my collaborator can make a "toy" example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the **NoView** bit of the Annotation dictionary entry /Flags is set, it's described in the PDF ISO 32000-1:2008 standard as:

> If set, do not display the annotation on the screen or allow it to interact with the user. The annotation may be printed (depending on the setting of the Print flag) but should be considered hidden for purposes of on-screen display and user interaction.

Comment: I suspect you are correct. But my colleague cannot work out where this is set, and does not have the time to debug this. He also has a workaround - to use the yellow "sticky notes" ("add note to replace text" in Adobe Reader) instead of the blue carets ("insert text at cursor" in Adobe Reader).

Comment: Now my collaborator has a workaround, he's unlikely to debug it in the near future. So since I can't check further, but suspect it is correct, I am marking this as correct.